# Problems with ticks in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to understand and see if it's possible to change the following:

I have a code that has 2 iterations. with the configuration exactly as it is. By clicking the setup-all button and then clicking the go once button 4 times. Call the second iteration. But, this second iteration starts at tick 1 and not at tick zero. Why does it happen? Is there a way to solve this?

```
globals [ iteration ]

patches-own [ scale-patch ]

to setup-world
  clearMethod
  random-seed 1  
  ifelse iteration = 0
  [setup-layers]
  [setup-layers-2]
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to clearMethod
  clear-ticks
  clear-turtles 
end

to setup-all
  clear-all
  random-seed 1  
  ifelse iteration = 0
  [setup-layers]
  [setup-layers-2]
 setup-turtles  
  reset-ticks
end


to setup-layers
  ask patches [
    set scale-patch random 10
    set pcolor scale-color blue scale-patch -8 12 ]   
end


to setup-layers-2
  ask patches [
    set scale-patch random 10
    set pcolor scale-color green scale-patch -8 12 ]  
end


to setup-turtles
   crt 1 [ set color black ] 
end


to go
moveproc
 let n count turtles
  if n = 0
  [
  ifelse iteration = 0
    [
      set iteration 1
      setup-world
    ]
    [
      stop
    ]
  ]
  
  tick
end


to moveproc
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    fd 1 
  if ticks >= 3
      [
          die
      ]
  ]
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment when you change iteration is within the `go` procedure (i.e. `set iteration 1 setup-world`). However, the `go` procedure also ends with `tick`. This means that when you change iteration NetLogo will first perform all the new setup things, which include `reset-ticks` (bringing ticks to 0), and then perform `tick` (bringing ticks to 1).

If you don't like this to happen and if you need to maintain this structure (i.e. `go` performing setup things), you can rearrange the `go` procedure so that `tick` happens **before** you check the condition for the change of iteration:

```
to go
  moveproc
  tick
  
  let n count turtles
  if n = 0 [
   ifelse iteration = 0
    [set iteration 1
     setup-world]
    [stop] 
  ]
end
```

PS: the one you provided is a great minimal reproducible example

Comment: Thank you so much Matteo for the solution and explanation :). Resolved! And thanks for the many tips on how to ask a question :)